# Calculate each overlapping date ranges from two independent databases in r

Tags: r, date-range

I have two independent two databases, one contains followup data (start date and end date). As follows:

```
> data1 <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2), "FUstart" = c("2019-01-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-10-01"), "FUend" = c("2019-03-31", "2019-06-30", "2019-09-30", "2019-12-31", "2019-06-30", "2019-09-30", "2019-12-31"))
> data1
  ID    FUstart      FUend
1  1 2019-01-01 2019-03-31
2  1 2019-04-01 2019-06-30
3  1 2019-07-01 2019-09-30
4  1 2019-10-01 2019-12-31
5  2 2019-04-01 2019-06-30
6  2 2019-07-01 2019-09-30
7  2 2019-10-01 2019-12-31
```

Another contains drug use data (also start date and end date). As follows:

```
> data2 <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,2), "Drugstart" = c("2019-01-11", "2019-03-26", "2019-06-26", "2019-03-20"), "Drugend" = c("2019-01-20", "2019-04-05", "2019-10-05", "2019-10-10"))
> data2
  ID  Drugstart    Drugend
1  1 2019-01-11 2019-01-20
2  1 2019-03-26 2019-04-05
3  1 2019-06-26 2019-10-05
4  2 2019-03-20 2019-10-10
```

The two databases are linked by "ID". The problem is that the rows for each ID may not be the same. I would like to calculate overlapping days and add it into the data1. I would expect to have the following results:

```
> data1
  ID    FUstart      FUend Overlapping.Days
1  1 2019-01-01 2019-03-31               16
2  1 2019-04-01 2019-06-30               10
3  1 2019-07-01 2019-09-30               92
4  1 2019-10-01 2019-12-31                5
5  2 2019-04-01 2019-06-30               91
6  2 2019-07-01 2019-09-30               92
7  2 2019-10-01 2019-12-31               10
```

Note that data1 is the basic database. And adds data2's overlapping days into data1. Many many thanks for helping~~

Comment: how overlapping.days 16 and 10 are calculated?? is first row of data1 is matched with first row of data2?

Comment: 1st row of data1 is related to 1st and 2nd rows of data2. In data2, from 2019-01-11 to 2019-01-20 (10 days) and from  2019-03-26 to 2019-03-31 (6 days) adds into data1. First day and final days also counted as overlapping days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using `data.table::foverlaps`:

```
foverlaps(data1, data2)[, 
    sum(1L + pmin(Drugend, FUend) - pmax(Drugstart, FUstart)), 
    .(ID, FUstart, FUend)]
```

output and I am also getting slightly diff numbers from OP's expected output:

```
   ID    FUstart      FUend V1
1:  1 2019-01-01 2019-03-31 16
2:  1 2019-04-01 2019-06-30 10
3:  1 2019-07-01 2019-09-30 92
4:  1 2019-10-01 2019-12-31  5
5:  2 2019-04-01 2019-06-30 91
6:  2 2019-07-01 2019-09-30 92
7:  2 2019-10-01 2019-12-31 10
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
cols <- paste0("FU", c("start","end"))
data1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols=cols]
setkeyv(data1, c("ID", cols))

#too lazy to generalize and hence copy paste
setDT(data2)
cols <- paste0("Drug", c("start","end"))
data2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols=cols]
setkeyv(data2, c("ID", cols))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have additional problem that first day and final days also counted as overlapping days. So this may be the reason for different output. For example, 1st row of data1 is related to 1st and 2nd rows of data2. In data2, from 2019-01-11 to 2019-01-20 (10 days) and from 2019-03-26 to 2019-03-31 (6 days) adds into data1 (Totally 16 days). But the your result is 14 days. Can this be resolved? Thank you~

Comment: Change pmin(Drugend, FUend) to pmin(Drugend+1, FUend+1) seems can resolve this.